# How to trace a fund transfer from Turkey Garanti bank to Wells Fargo bank in US?

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, transfer, turkey

I transfered $25,000 from Garanti bank in Turkey to my closed account at Wells Fargo bank in the US.

How can I out where funds went after being rejected by Wells Fargo bank (because my account number was closed a year ago)?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get in touch with the Bank from where the funds transfer was initiated; Turkey Garanti Bank. Specifically file a complaint, Beneficiary Claims non-receipt of transferred funds.

They should be able to advise you what happened to the funds and where they are currently.

Ideally Wells Fargo would send the funds back to the Originating Bank.

Note there would be some fees deducted few hundreds of dollars.

Comment: Thanks for info, would you please tell me where should I file a complaint, Beneficiary Claims non-receipt of transferred funds.